# Simple ajax php submit form

Tags: php, ajax

How do you use ajax to submit form contents to a txt file.

```
<input id="form" placeholder="fill out this" type="text">
<button>Submit</button>
```

ajax

```
<script>

$('button').click(function (){
var food = $('#form').val();
 $.ajax({
            url:'form.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: food,


        });
});

</script>
```

form.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $data = $_POST['food'];
    $f = fopen('filehere.txt', 'w+');
    fwrite($f, $data);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

the txt file keeps coming up blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your ajax request, more precisely `data` part. You can achieve your goal on two ways.

## 1. Editing existing code

Just instead

```
data: food,
```

use

```
data: {
  food: food
}
```

## 2. In my opinion more elegant

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" type="text"/>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Nothing complicated, just simple form in HTML.

```
$('#myForm > button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default behaviour
    var formData = $('#myForm').serialize() //serialize data from form
    $.ajax({
        //everything as before
        data: formData
    });
});
```

Here you serialize data from **form**. It will work as same as you send normal form. So now in PHP you get data form `$_POST` global array using form name. For example

```
$input = $_POST['myInput'];
```

---

Your problem is you didn't 'give' a name for your data. You just sent a data, but PHP couldn't identify this by name.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX call with wrong type, you have to send an object.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'test.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {food: food}
});
```